# Extract the position of one date in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm looking for a way to cut my dataframe at one precise date, so I thought about enter this date in my code, and then, extract the position of where it is and then just slice my dataframe with that position as the end of the df.

Here is my code :

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from pathlib import Path 
import re  
from datetime import date

DAY_CHOOSEN = pd.DataFrame() 
out=pd.DataFrame()
temp = read_csv("data.csv",sep=";")
DAY_CHOOSEN=date(day=23,month=4,year=year_)
for row in temp[0] : 
   if row [0] == DAY_CHOOSEN : 
       index=row
temp=temp[:index]              
out = pd.merge(out,temp,left_index = True, right_index = True,how = 'outer')    
print(f"{name} a ete traite")
```

But when I launch my code, I obviously have this error :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\E31\Documents\cours\stage_dossier\projet_python\extract_period.py", line 40, in <module>
    if row ['dte_'+str(year_)] == DAY_CHOOSEN :
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is a link to download an example of my file.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/86xw88k8b1f530s/data.csv/file
How can I manage with this ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you boil this down to a [mre]? To me there seems to be a lot of code shown that is not relevant for the actual question. But basically, with pandas dataframes, you'll want to avoid iteration. E.g. you can get the "position" of a certain index value with [get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html).

Comment: I edited my post, I'm now reading about get_loc thanks

Comment: I just tried with get_loc but i got this error : ```raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: datetime.date(1981, 4, 23)```

Comment: Ok, `get_loc` may be overly complicated here. I've added an answer with a way that I think is easier. This is pretty much pandas basics; the point here is to use the pandas built-in datetime, not the Python standard lib datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily slice your data based on a certain date if you parse the column that contains the date information to datetime datatype. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', decimal=',')

# to datetime
df['dte_1981'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dte_1981'], dayfirst=True)

# now you can slice your df...
DAY_CHOOSEN = pd.Timestamp('1981-04-23')
df_select = df[df['dte_1981'] > DAY_CHOOSEN]


df_select
      dte_1981 res_1981    SQ_x
113 1981-04-24       2.5  -2.05
114 1981-04-25       2.5  -2.05
115 1981-04-26       2.5  -2.05
....
```